# How can I append an array of list in dynamodb using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I want to append a list of array in dynamodb using python. I am using boto for the same. I am able to append the list in python and saving it in a variable. Now just wanted to append that value in an item (list of array) which is empty right now and don't know how to do it. So it would be great if anyone can help me with that.

```
        result = self.User_Connection.scan(main_user__eq=self.username)
        for connection_details in result:
            main_user = connection_details['main_user']
            connection_list = connection_details['connections']
            connection_list.append(frnd_user_id)
```

I want to add this **connection_list.append(frnd_user_id)** as an item.
I've tried doing like this:-

```
        if user_connections['connections'] == None:
            self.User_Connection.put_item(data={'connections' : set(frnd_user_id)})
        else:
            self.User_Connection.update_item(Key = {user_connections['id']}, UpdateExpression="SET connections = list_append(connections, :i)",
                                             ExpressionAttributeValues={':i': [frnd_user_id],})
```

but it is not working. Giving error:-

> 'Table' has no attribute 'update_item'

I've tried doing like this too:-

```
result = self.User_Connection.scan(main_user__eq=self.username)
        for connection_details in result:
            main_user = connection_details['main_user']
            main_userid = connection_details['id']
            connection_list = connection_details['connections']
            print connection_list


            if connection_details['connections'] == None:

                self.User_Connection.put_item(data={'id' : main_userid,
                                                        'main_user':self.username,
                                                        'connections[]' : frnd_user_id})
            else:
                item = self.User_Connection.get_item(id = connection_details['id'])
                for i in frnd_user_id:
                    item[connection_list].append(i)
                item.save(overwrite=True)
```

this is showing error too.

> unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Any error message?

Comment: @helloV yeah it is saying 'Table' has no attribute 'update_item'